# How to adjust position of embedded MailChimp form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, mailchimp

I have an embedded MailChimp signup form in the footer of my WordPress site using a raw HTML widget in my theme's page builder.

I managed to get the input field and subscribe button on the same line thanks to some help I got on this site. Now I just need to remove some of the empty space between the field and the button and center everything.

Here's a link to my site, the form is right at the bottom:

http://origamidotme.staging.wpengine.com

Here's the code for my form:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#1b1d1f; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
#mce-EMAIL {display:inline-block; float:left; margin: 6px 20px 0 0;}
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://origami.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=c46543dec276193775d525c9f&amp;id=85cb8a5e0e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" size="100%" placeholder="Your Best Email" required>
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">.  <input type="text" name="b_c46543dec276193775d525c9f_85cb8a5e0e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn border-width-0 btn-accent btn-round btn-flat"></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Any idea what I need to add to bring that button closer to the end of the field and then how to make the whole thing centered in my footer?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the code like this :

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<style type="text/css">
  #mc_embed_signup {
    background: #1b1d1f;
    clear: left;
    font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #mce-EMAIL {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
  }
  /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="https://origami.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=c46543dec276193775d525c9f&amp;id=85cb8a5e0e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

      <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" size="100%" placeholder="Your Best Email" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn border-width-0 btn-accent btn-round btn-flat">
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">. <input type="text" name="b_c46543dec276193775d525c9f_85cb8a5e0e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```